# Replace current selected word in Notepad++ to HREF (popup available?)

Tags: notepad++

For this instance I perfer working in Notepad++ instead of a WYSIWYG editor.

Short explained, in Notepad++ I would like to select a word in the following text:

```
Noble hops conditioning secondary fermentation, units of bitterness
```

For example, secondary fermentation, and replace it with HTML AHREF, like this:

1. Select the word with mouse (so it turns green, not in Find/Replace)
2. Hit a keyboard shortcut to a Notepad++ macro
3. A popup pops up with a form and let's me paste in a link (http://)
4. Word gets replaced with a AHREF with the selected word as an anchortext and correct linking.

`<a href="">$0</a>` is something I came up with, but it does only 33% of the job.

Did not found any suggestion in [the list of regular expressions](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions) that replacering selected word is possible.

If this is impossible I would still be glad to get some alternatives to fast and easy make AHREFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Open **shortcuts.xml**

Path (For Windows 7) is `C:\Users\CHANGETHISUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++`

Add this macro to the file and save:

```
        <Macro name="href" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="no" Key="65">
            <Action type="0" message="2177" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&lt;" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="a" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam=" " />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="h" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="r" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="e" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="f" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="=" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam='&quot;' />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="#" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam='&quot;' />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&gt;" />
            <Action type="0" message="2179" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&lt;" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="/" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="a" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="&gt;" />
            <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="#" />
            <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="768" sParam="" />
            <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1" sParam="" />
        </Macro>
```

Open Notepad++, shortcut is CTRL+ALT+A

Now `selected text` will be replaced with `<a href="#">selected text</a>` and `#` will be marked so a link can be easily be added.